# Undefined reference while defining a class destructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I am working on a small project to improve my OOP skills in C++ - the project is just a simple collection of books, sort of a home library, where the books can be stored in virtual shelves, grouped into bigger bookstands with respective names etc, with each book additionally having its own ID, being a positive integer. I was trying to create a user-defined class destructor and I wanted to move the destructor's implementation to a source file, following the rule to move longer than one-line-long implementations to a ***.cpp*** file from ***.hpp*** file to help building up a habit of producing a better optimized and faster code (of course in this example it will not help, but I just want to find a solution to the encountered problem, not to struggle in the future).

However, when trying to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/bookshelf.dir/objects.a(bookshelf.cpp.obj): in function `void std::_Destroy<Book>(Book*)':
c:/mingw/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:98: undefined reference to `Book::~Book()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bookshelf.dir/build.make:101: bookshelf.exe] Error 1
make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/bookshelf.dir/all] Error 2
make.exe: *** [Makefile:111: all] Error 2
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command cmake --build Build" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I use Visual Studio Code and compile my code with the MinGW64 compiler, working on Windows 11, and my project is set up with the following CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Book VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# include(GoogleTest)
# enable_testing()

add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_executable(book src/book.cpp include/bookshelf.hpp include/book.hpp include/types.hpp include/helpers.hpp)
add_executable(bookshelf src/bookshelf.cpp include/bookshelf.hpp)
# add_executable(library src/library.cpp include/library.hpp)

add_compile_options(-Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -unused-variable)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

include_directories(
    include
    src
)
```

Here's the code, both for the header and the source file:
***book.cpp***

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include "book.hpp"
#include "helpers.hpp"

Book::~Book(){
    ids.erase(book_id_);
    freed_ids.insert(book_id_);
    //@TODO: To be implemented - destroy the object, not only deal with the book's ID!
};

Book::Book(Title title, Author author) : title_(title), author_(author){
    if(!freed_ids.empty()){
    book_id_ = *(freed_ids.begin());
}
else if(freed_ids.empty() && !ids.empty()){
    book_id_ = *(ids.end());
}
else{
    book_id_ = 0;
}
ids.insert(book_id_);
};

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, from book.cpp!" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***book.hpp***

```
#ifndef book
#define book

#include "types.hpp"
#include "helpers.hpp"

/*
Class represeting a book as en entry in a collection of books.
@param author_  Author of the book.
@param title_   Title of the book. 
@param book_id_ ID of a book. 
*/
class Book{
    private:
    Author author_;
    Title title_;
    BookID book_id_;

    public:
    Book(Title title, Author author);

    /*Get the title of the book.
    @TODO: To be moved into a new class Library*/
    Title get_title() const {return title_;}
    
    /*Get the author of the book.
    @TODO: To be moved into a new class Library*/
    Author get_author() const {return author_;}
    
    /*Get the ID number of the book.
    @TODO: To be moved into a new class Library*/
    BookID get_id() const {return book_id_;}

    ~Book();
};



#endif
```

Simply moving the destructor's body to the ***.hpp*** file makes the code compile just fine, but that is no solution to my problem. The constructor defined in the ***.cpp*** file works just fine, and I don't get it why the destructor does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. If something makes no sense in my code and is just stupid, feel free to tell me as well, intel like that would be very much appreciated.

@user17732522 I have applied the changes you suggested me in the answer below and the problem with the destructor does not occur now, but instead I get errors stating that there are multiple definitions of std::set objects I used to store IDs and names - they look like this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 CMakeFiles/main.dir/objects.a(bookshelf.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Darek/Desktop/projects/myLibrary/include/helpers.hpp:9: multiple definition of `ids';
 CMakeFiles/main.dir/objects.a(book.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Darek/Desktop/projects/myLibrary/include/helpers.hpp:9: first defined here
```

And two similar errors are present along with that one, except they refer to freed_ids and shelf_names std::set-type objects.

Here is the ***helpers.hpp*** file, not very complicated:

```
#ifndef HELPERS_HEADER_GUARD
#define HELPERS_HEADER_GUARD

#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include "types.hpp"

std::set<BookID> ids;
std::set<BookID> freed_ids;   
std::set<ShelfName> shelf_names;

#endif
```

And the ***bookshelf.cpp*** file also present in the error message:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>

#include "bookshelf.hpp"

Bookshelf::Bookshelf(ShelfName shelf_name){
    if(std::find(shelf_names.begin(), shelf_names.end(), shelf_name) != shelf_names.end()){
        throw(std::invalid_argument("A bookshelf with the given name already exists."));
    }
    else{
        shelf_name_ = shelf_name;
        // content_ = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you want a single `add_executable` that lists all source files, not three separate `add_executable` entries.

Comment: `#ifndef book
#define book`: That is really dangerous. How likely do you think it is that you will try to use `book` as an identifier somewhere? The header guard name should be as unique as possible. It is also customary for macro names to be all uppercase. It should include at least the full file name and I would also include e.g. `HEADER_GUARD` or something along the lines in it.

Comment: You should not put include files into `add_executable` command, and on another side each `add_executable` must list all sources necessary to build this executable

Comment: recommend `target_compile_options` and `target_include_directories` instead of the general-form ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting your program into multiple:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_executable(book src/book.cpp include/bookshelf.hpp include/book.hpp include/types.hpp include/helpers.hpp)
add_executable(bookshelf src/bookshelf.cpp include/bookshelf.hpp)
```

You want only one executable. Furthermore, the header files do not belong there:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp src/book.cpp src/bookshelf.cpp)
```

(Btw. why is `main.cpp` not in `src`?)

On the other hand `include_directories` should include only the `include` directory:

```
include_directories(
    include
)
```

---

The reason for the undefined reference error is, that with your original configuration, CMake will create three independent programs. Consider only this one:

```
add_executable(bookshelf src/bookshelf.cpp include/bookshelf.hpp)
```

It will be build by compiling `src/bookshelf.cpp`, but not with `src/book.cpp`. (The `.hpp` files shouldn't matter here, but still don't belong in the command.).

So `bookshelf.cpp` probably contains some (member) variable of type `Book`. In order to use this variable, the program needs to know how to construct and destruct a variable of that type. In other words, it needs to have a definition of the constructor and destructor of `Book`. But the *definition* of both is only in the file `book.cpp`, which is not included in *this* program compilation.

Comment: Thank you, it is all valuable information for me and I will keep that in mind, nevertheless it does not answer the question (or I just do not see the answer in what you wrote) - why do I get this undefined reference error? I'd be glad if you explained a little, since I am not a very experienced person :)

Comment: @dkrolicki Before I explain it in detail, can you please verify whether the change fixes your problem? Also I just now realize that you have a `main` function in `book.cpp`. There should be only one `main` function, usually in `main.cpp`. Your exact question is hard to answer since you claim "The constructor defined in the .cpp file works just fine, and I don't get it why the destructor does not work.", but from all the information I have, the constructor should result in the same error. Either there is something missing from the rest of your code or you are mistaken.

Comment: I have applied the changes you suggested me and the problem with the destructor does not occur now,  but instead I get errors stating that there are multiple definitions of std::set objects I used to store IDs and names EDIT I wanted to paste the code here, but I will do it below, since it is not possible in the comments section.

Comment: @dkrolicki You can edit your question to _add_ more details (please don't remove the original code). But anyway, that seems to be a new separate problem from the original one.

Comment: @dkrolicki I have added a small explanation for the original error. I assume that you were mistaken about the difference between constructor and destructor.